# MATCH(title) AGAINST('test 11' IN BOOLEAN MODE) can't search number

Tags: mysql

this query is not working for the number and only returns result related with the test. There have rows with 11 but nothing returns when search 11. what is the problem

```
   SELECT *, MATCH(title) AGAINST('test 11' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS     Score FROM search_table WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MATCH(title) AGAINST('test 11' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY  `score`  DESC ,`date`  DESC
```

Comment: Check your `ft_min_word_len` in  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and default is 4 that needs to be decreased for searching lesser word length.

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty thanks. I have godaddy hosting how to change ft_min_word_len  in this hosting?

Comment: Well I have no idea how you can do it on `godaddy` may be call the customer support and see what they have to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhik Chakraborty